# jQuery Hover Slider starts again when the mouse is moved

Tags: jquery, hover, slider

i am trying to put an image on my website and when you hover over it, the image slides down and reveals text behind it.

I have got this to work, however if i move the mouse slightly while over the image it will move again.

Here is the jQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.show').hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({top:'400px'});
},function(){
    $(this).animate({top:'0px'});
    });
});
```

Here is the css:

```
.hover {
width: 300px;
height: 400px;
background: black;
margin-top: 10px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
 }

.show {
width: 300px;
height: 400px;
background: red;
position: absolute;
 }
```

Is there a way to make it stop on the hovered state until the mouse is moved completely off the div?

Here is the JSFiddle as requested [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HPSFQ/)

Comment: cat you une fiddle so we could see how it works with html

Comment: Added my answer, with fiddle too ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the delegated modele ...

```
$(function(){
$('#combo').on('mouseover',function(e){
   var $t = $(e.target);
    if( $t.is('img') ){
       $t.animate({top:'89px'});  
       return false;
    }
}).on('mouseout',function(e){
   var $t = $(e.target), $img = $(this).children('img');
    if( e.target == this && e.relatedTarget != $img.get(0) ){
        $img.clearQueue().animate({top:'10px'});
       return false;        
    }
})
});
```

Fiddle [-HERE-](http://jsfiddle.net/59d59/)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `.stop(true,true)`:

```
$('.show').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop(true,true).animate({
        top: '400px'
    });
}, function() {
    $(this).stop(true,true).animate({
        top: '0px'
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are moving the image so there's a `mouseout` event, which causes the hover close function to be called.  What you want to do is to use separate `mouseover`/`mouseout` events like so:

```
$('.show').mouseover( function() {
    $(this).animate( {top: '300px'} );
});

$('.hover').mouseout( function() {
    $('.show').animate( {top: '0px'} );
});
```

See my solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/zRn5w/

The only problem with this solution is that if you move the mouse down to the image, it momentarily slides back up because the `mouseout` event gets called on `.hover`.  That will be a slightly trickier problem to solve...I would probably expand the height of `.hover` at the same time I was moving the image so that the `mouseout` area would be correct.

​